# getting same value in every hashmap variable.why?

Tags: android

code is:

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
HashMap<String, String> question1 = readJsonObject(jsonResponse.getJSONObject("1"), map);
HashMap<String, String> question2 = readJsonObject(jsonResponse.getJSONObject("2"), map);
HashMap<String, String> question3 = readJsonObject(jsonResponse.getJSONObject("3"), map);

q1.setText(question1.get("question"));    //q1,q2,q3 are textviews
q2.setText(question2.get("question"));
q3.setText(question3.get("question"));
```

this is readJsonObject method/function:

```
private HashMap<String,String> readJsonObject(JSONObject jsonObject,HashMap<String, String> map ) throws JSONException {
    map.put("question", jsonObject.getString("question"));
    map.put("optiona", jsonObject.getString("optiona"));
    map.put("optionb", jsonObject.getString("optionb"));
    map.put("optionc", jsonObject.getString("optionc"));
    map.put("optiond", jsonObject.getString("optiond"));
    map.put("correct", jsonObject.getString("correct"));
    return map;
}
```

but i am getting same string value in q1 q2 q4 TextViews. please solve this.

response getting from the server:

```
{
"0":[],

"success":true,

"1":{ "question":"question3",
      "optiona":"optiona",
      "optionb":"optionb",
      "optionc":"optionc",
      "optiond":"optiond",
      "correct":"optiona"},

"2":{ "question":"question1",
      "optiona":"optiona",
      "optionb":"optionb",
      "optionc":"optionc",
      "optiond":"optiond",
      "correct":"optiond"},

"3":{ "question":"question4",
      "optiona":"optiona",
      "optionb":"optionb",
      "optionc":"optionc",
      "optiond":"optiond",
      "correct":"optionc"}
}
```

getting different value from server in response but q1,q2,q3 showing same values. why? please solve this

if i am adding map.clear() after every readJsonObject() textview becomes blank,,,,, and if i add map.clear in readJsonObject() no change still same value in q1,q2,q3

if i use different hashmap in every time calling readJsonObject getting right answer but i think it is not efficient. right?

Comment: Clear the HashMap everytime you enter readJsonObject

Comment: if i am adding map.clear() after every readJsonObject() textview becomes blank,,,,, and if i add map.clear in readJsonObject() no change still same value in q1,q2,q3

Comment: if i use different hashmap in every time calling readJsonObject getting right answer but i think it is not efficient. right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the method to this

```
private HashMap<String,String> readJsonObject(JSONObject jsonObject ) throws JSOException {
HashMap<String, String> tempMap = new HashMap<>();
tempMap.put("question", jsonObject.getString("question"));
tempMap.put("optiona", jsonObject.getString("optiona"));
tempMap.put("optionb", jsonObject.getString("optionb"));
tempMap.put("optionc", jsonObject.getString("optionc"));
tempMap.put("optiond", jsonObject.getString("optiond"));
tempMap.put("correct", jsonObject.getString("correct"));
return tempMap;
}
```